# How to translate the entire pandas dataframe into another language using googletrans in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-translate

I want the translate the language of the entire dataframe into English. The dataframe contains the data from excel sheet. While trying to run the following code, I am getting this error -TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable

```
translator = Translator()
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_name)
df = df.apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest="en").text)
print(df)
```

Comment: Try applying .to_array to your x variable inside the translate function. `df = df.apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x.to_array(), dest="en").text)`

Comment: Now I am getting this error:    AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_array'

Comment: Can you post a sample of df?